# Problems rotating xtick labels when using twinx

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, rotation, axis-labels

I have problems with the rotation of my X-axis, I have tried to do the rotation the output plot without errors, but I do not have the results.

```
# Import Data
#df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/selva86/datasets/raw/master/economics.csv")
x = total_test["Dia"].values[:]; y1 = total_test["Confirmados"].values[:]; y2 = total_test["Fallecidos"].values[:]

# Plot Line1 (Left Y Axis)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,8), dpi= 200)
ax1.plot(x, y1,'g^', color='tab:red')

# Plot Line2 (Right Y Axis)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.plot(x, y2,'bs', color='tab:blue')

# Just Decorations!! -------------------
# ax1 (left y axis)
ax1.set_xlabel('Dias', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_ylabel('Personas Confirmadas', color='tab:red', fontsize=20)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0, labelcolor='tab:red' )

# ax2 (right Y axis)
ax2.set_ylabel("Personas Fallecidas", color='tab:blue', fontsize=20)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0, labelcolor='tab:blue')
ax2.set_title("Personas Confirmadas y Fallecidas por Covid-19 Peru", fontsize=15)
#ax2.set_xticks(x)
ax2.set_xticklabels(x[::],fontsize=10,rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Any commands for the xaxis need to occur before `ax2`.
- Verify date is in a `datetime` format and set as the index.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/selva86/datasets/raw/master/economics.csv")

# verify the date column is a datetime format and set as index
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

#plot
# create figure
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,8))

# 1st plot
ax1.plot(df['pop'], color='tab:red')

# set xticks rotation before creating ax2
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# 2nd plot (Right Y Axis)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # create the 'twin' axis on the right
ax2.plot(df['unemploy'], color='tab:blue')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

- Plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
# load data
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/selva86/datasets/raw/master/economics.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])

# plot and rotate the tick labels with rot= in the first plot call
ax = df.plot(y='pop', color='tab:red', figsize=(10,8), rot=90)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.plot(y='unemploy', color='tab:blue', ax=ax2)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much "xaxis need to occur before ax2." works!